# Spring Boot - Microservice - Zuul - Secured Annotation

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I have Zuul Proxy as gateway application running in 8080 and Project Application running as micro-service in 8090. I am trying to create a project via Rest Controller, but when i am trying to access the url, am facing access denied issue and getting response as 401.

Project Micro-Service

Project Application

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "packagename")
public class ProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

If I comment the GlobalSecurity Annotation, it works perfectly. But Authority check is not happening.

ProjectController

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ApplicationConstant.API_PATH_PROJECT)
public class ProjectController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectController.class);

    @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

    @Secured({ RoleConstant.ROLE_ADMIN_PROJECT})
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
    @RequestMapping(value = ApplicationConstant.API_PATH_CREATE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@ModelAttribute ProjectRequest projectRequest, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws ApiException, IOException, ParseException {
     ....
 }
}
```

Gateway/Zuul Properties

```
server.port=8080

eureka.client.enabled=true
eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true

#zuul.ignored-headers=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
```

Discovery Microservice Property

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXXXXXX
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXXXXX

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false

server.port = 8094

eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://discUser:discPassword@localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

Comment: In order to make `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` to work properly , you have to first setup the Spring security to authenticate the request such that Spring security know who the user is . So what is your spring security configuration ?

Comment: @KenChan I have updated the configuration